# Bootstrap 3 Navbar - When hovering a link, color shows up as #EEEEEE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I do not have it set up anywhere in the stylesheet for hovering a link to be #EEEEEE, I am wanting the navbar hover to be the same color as the navbar background so that you can't see any difference when it is hovered.

Here is my current stylesheet: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SzTZurpB)

Here is a demo of the site as it currently stands:
[Link](http://tobi29.ignorelist.com/)

Comment: It's better if you can paste the code samples into the question so that people can see the code to get help in the future if those links go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default `hover` state of Bootstrap:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

You already have a selector that can override this, just include the `background` property:

```
#header a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet.

```
ul.nav a:hover { color: #fff !important; }
```